# Partially interpreted Const in z3

Tags: z3, smt

In z3, one can declare a fully-uninterpreted `const` like so:

```
(declare-const x Int)
```

Similarly, one can define a fully-interpreted one like this:

```
(define-fun y () Int 3)
; y == 3
```

Given an algebraic datatype, one can have a fully interpreted tuple like the following:

```
(declare-datatypes () ((Item (mk-item (size Int) (weight Int)))))
(define-fun z () Item (mk-item 3 4))
; z == Item(size=3, weight=4)
```

... Or a non-interpreted one like below:

```
(declare-const i1 (Item Int Int))
```

Now is it possible to have a partially-interpreted data type, so that, based on the previous example, `weight` would be fixed for each item and `size` could vary?

```
; (bad syntax, but I hope you get the idea)
; in this case the size is varying, but weight is fixed to 5
(declare-const i2 (Item Int 5))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply declare it with `declare-fun` and assert an equality for the portions that you know:

```
(declare-datatypes () ((Item (mk-item (size Int) (weight Int)))))

(declare-fun x () Item)
(assert (= (weight x) 5))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

This produces:

```
sat
(model
  (define-fun x () Item
    (mk-item 0 5))
)
```